# Gitlab CI execution error but pipeline success

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a simple project .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

stages:
 - build

build-and-run-tests:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - call npm install
    - call npm run build-client-in-target
    - call npm run run-tests-on-target
```

when I start the build pipeline, it fails while executing `build-client-in-target`, but the pipeline continues with success status

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due to the call command which doesn't return the error. Can't you call directly npm ?

Answer (score 0):

you should move all preprocessing to `before_script` tag
and remove the call command

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

stages:
 - build

build-and-run-tests:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows
  before_script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build-client-in-target
  script:
    - npm run run-tests-on-targe
```